# Split text from columns and then rewrite after processing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to split a text on spaces () and paste them in separate columns in sheet 2. I also want to remove "Hello" from the text before/after splitting the texts in columns. I was successful in using `getValues.split(" ")`, but unsuccessful in pasting the new values in my destination range (in sheet2).

Input:

[image: current look]

Output:

[image: output]

My current code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lr = ss1.getLastRow();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {
    var title = ss1.getRange(i, 1).getValue().split(" ");
    ss2.getRange(i, 2).setValue(title[0]);
  }
}
```

Any help rendered would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. It doesn't include your headings as I'm not sure what you'd like to do with that exactly. It does take care of stripping the "hello" word from your string and put every word in its separate column. Comments in the code explain why I'm doing stuff.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Selects the spreadsheet
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Selects sheet 1
  var data = ss1.getDataRange().getValues(); // Gets all values in the sheet
  var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // Selects sheet 2

  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var words = data[i][0].split(" "); // Create an array of all words
    if (words[0].toLowerCase().indexOf('hello') > -1) { // True when the first word of the sentence contains hello
      words.splice(0, 1); // Remove 1 item, starting from position 0 - remove the word that contains hello
    }
    // Get range on Sheet2, same row number as sheet 1, starting from column 1, select 1 row, and the same amount of columns as the amount of words
    // Because we set values for a range that can span multiple rows, we put the words array in another array (where the words array represents one row)
    // We add 1 to variable i as the index of an array starts at 0 instead of 1.
    ss2.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, words.length).setValues([words])
  }
}
```

[Tested in this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19YVlz9BPI7T4QXKT_rKkJXENKoH1TMueGBRUTf-4mco/edit?usp=sharing)